# Unable to resolve missing qt4 dependecies after installing Armory and PPAs for Bitcoins

Tags: dependencies

I've decided to make a wallet trough Armory so I can transfer Bitcoins to cold storage, so I went to install Armory.

Now, Armory installed all well and good and than asked me to install PPAs, which I followed the install procedure. Then I got an error.

I was saying that qt4 based programs are needed along with python-qt4 for armory, the dependencies. Now I tried this to resolve them:

```
sudo apt-get check
```

This is what I get:

```
lipovi@lipovi:~$ sudo apt-get check
[sudo] password for lipovi: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libqt4-designer : Depends: libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6 is installed
Depends: libqt4-xml (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6 is installed
Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6 is installed
Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6 is installed

libqt4-dev : Depends: libqt4-designer (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4 is installed
Depends: libqt4-help (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4 is installed
Depends: libqt4-scripttools (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4 is installed
Depends: libqt4-test (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4 is installed

libqt4-help : Depends: libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6 is     installed
Depends: libqt4-sql (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6 is installed
Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6 is installed
Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6 is installed

libqt4-qt3support : Depends: libqt4-designer (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6) but     4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4 is installed

libqt4-scripttools : Depends: libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4) but     4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6 is installed
Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6 is installed
Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6 is installed

libqt4-test : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4) but 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Then I tried this:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This is what it prints out:

```
lipovi@lipovi:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-scripttools libqt4-test
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-scripttools libqt4-test
4 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/4,155 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-designer:
 libqt4-designer depends on libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4); however:
  Version of libqt4-script on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6.
 libqt4-designer depends on libqt4-xml (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4); however:
  Version of libqt4-xml on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6.
 libqt4-designer depends on libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4); however:
  Version of libqtcore4 on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6.
 libqt4-designer depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4); however:
  Version of libqtgui4 on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-designer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-help:
 libqt4-help depends on libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4); however:
  Version of libqt4-network on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6.
 libqt4-help depends on libqt4-sql (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4); however:
  Version of libqt4-sql on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6.
 libqt4-help depends on libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4); however:
  Version of libqtcore4 on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6.
 libqt4-help depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4); however:
  Version of libqtgui4 on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-help (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-scripttools:
 libqt4-scripttools depends on libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4); however:
  Version of libqt4-script on system isNo apport report written because the error     message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                 No apport report     written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a     previous failure.
           No apport report written because the error message indicates its a     followup error from a previous failure.
                                     No apport report written because the error     message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                               No apport report     written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
         No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup     error from a previous failure.
                                    4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6.
 libqt4-scripttools depends on libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4); however:
  Version of libqtcore4 on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6.
 libqt4-scripttools depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4); however:
  Version of libqtgui4 on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-scripttools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-test:
 libqt4-test depends on libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4); however:
  Version of libqtcore4 on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-test (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-qt4:
 python-qt4 depends on libqt4-designer (>= 4:4.8.0-1~); however:
  Package libqt4-designer is not configured yet.
 python-qt4 depends on libqt4-help (>= 4:4.8.0-1~); however:
  Package libqt4-help is not configured yet.
 python-qt4 depends on libqt4-scripttools (>= 4:4.8.0-1~); however:
  Package libqt4-scripttools is not configured yet.
 python-qt4 depends on libqt4-test (>= 4:4.8.0-1~); however:
  Package libqt4-test is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing python-qt4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of armory:
 armory depends on python-qt4; however:
  Package python-qt4 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing armory (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libqt4-designer
 libqt4-help
 libqt4-scripttools
 libqt4-test
 python-qt4
 armory
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And after the previous command, this:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

It prints almost the same thing.

I tried too:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

The print out is this:

```
lipovi@lipovi:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-designer:
 libqt4-designer depends on libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4); however:
  Version of libqt4-script on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6.
 libqt4-designer depends on libqt4-xml (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4); however:
  Version of libqt4-xml on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6.
 libqt4-designer depends on libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4); however:
  Version of libqtcore4 on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6.
 libqt4-designer depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4); however:
  Version of libqtgui4 on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-designer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-help:
 libqt4-help depends on libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4); however:
  Version of libqt4-network on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6.
 libqt4-help depends on libqt4-sql (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4); however:
  Version of libqt4-sql on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6.
 libqt4-help depends on libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4); however:
  Version of libqtcore4 on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6.
 libqt4-help depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4); however:
  Version of libqtgui4 on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-help (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-scripttools:
 libqt4-scripttools depends on libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4); however:
  Version of libqt4-script on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6.
 libqt4-scripttools depends on libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4); however:
  Version of libqtcore4 on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6.
 libqt4-scripttools depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4); however:
  Version of libqtgui4 on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-scripttools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-qt4:
 python-qt4 depends on libqt4-designer (>= 4:4.8.0-1~); however:
  Package libqt4-designer is not configured yet.
 python-qt4 depends on libqt4-help (>= 4:4.8.0-1~); however:
  Package libqt4-help is not configured yet.
 python-qt4 depends on libqt4-scripttools (>= 4:4.8.0-1~); however:
  Package libqt4-scripttools is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing python-qt4 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-test:
 libqt4-test depends on libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.4); however:
  Version of libqtcore4 on system is 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.6.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-test (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of armory:
 armory depends on python-qt4; however:
  Package python-qt4 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing armory (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libqt4-designer
 libqt4-help
 libqt4-scripttools
 python-qt4
 libqt4-test
 armory
```

Whatever I do, it won't resolve it.

Now, I would really nicely ask if someone had this problem and, by chance, offer a solution, I'd be really grateful.

The coins are on my phone I would like to move them as soon as possible from it.

P.S. Don't ask for them......

Comment: 1) What version of Ubuntu are you running 2) How did you install Armory?

Comment: 1) Ubuntu 12.04
2) Went to the Armory website, downloaded tar.gz, un-packed it and followed the installation instructions on the website.

Comment: Why did you download the tar.gz instead of the .deb files for 12.04? https://bitcoinarmory.com/download/

Comment: That's the site I've downloaded the packed .deb files. They are all in that tar.gz file.

Comment: There are tar.gz files under the Linux logo (Tux, the penguin), and under the Ubuntu logo there are DEB-files. I suspect you downloaded the tar.gz files without really having to, making this unnecessarily complicated. Anyway, I see you have resolved this by reinstalling the packages :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below commands on terminal to force remove all the unconfigured packages,

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq libqt4-designer
sudo dpkg -P --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq libqt4-help
sudo dpkg -P --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq libqt4-scripttools
sudo dpkg -P --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq libqt4-test
sudo dpkg -P --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq python-qt4
sudo dpkg -P --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq armory
```

Then try to install all the packages via `apt-get`,

```
sudo apt-get install libqt4-designer
sudo apt-get install libqt4-help
sudo apt-get install libqt4-scripttools
sudo apt-get install libqt4-test
sudo apt-get install python-qt4
sudo apt-get install armory
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! No dependencies left, now I can install Armory again without being blocked by something missing. You're a life saver, man!